# Strange behavior in CSS priority with Flask and Bootstrap

Tags: python, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flask

There are a few things happening with my CSS sheet that I don't understand. I tried to empty my custom CSS stylesheet to only the bare minimum, and I think it's a problem with priority, though I can't figure it out.

The first is that my custom CSS on an h1 tag does not seem to work unless I reference it or its parent tag previously within my CSS sheet. I.e.

```html
// This does not do anything:
#main-title {
    font-size: 63px;
}
```

But this works:

```html
.title-body {
}
#main-title {
    font-size: 63px;
}
```

And I'm not sure why. I've seen other SO answers about priority and the relative "strengths" of a class vs. id  and such, and even writing `h1#main-title` doesn't work.

The second issue is that I can't get my `body` tag to fill the entire height of the viewport. Again, I've searched extensively on SO for answers to this, so right now my custom CSS sheet includes:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

And nothing works. If I put those same exact things inside a `style` tag within `head`, it works like a charm, but I want to know why putting it in the stylesheet isn't working. I've also tried some things like setting `overflow: auto;` and trying `height: 100vh;`. Any help would be appreciated.

I'm using python 3.5, Flask, and Bootstrap. My base-layout looks like this:

```
<!doctype html>

<head>
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
    <link href="static/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/new_style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="static/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    {% block navbar %}
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" style="background: transparent; border: 0;">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse"
                      data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url_for('index') }}">Title</a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="{{ url_for('about') }}">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="{{ url_for('contact') }}">Contact</a></li>
                    <li><a href="{{ url_for('test') }}">Testing</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    {% endblock %}

    <div id="holder">
        <div id="content-div" class="container-fluid">
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
            {% block footer %}
                <p>
                    Copyright © Me All Rights Reserved
                </p>
            {% endblock %}
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

And the main home page that extends that base layout looks like this:

```
{% extends "base_layout.html" %}
{% block title %}Title{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<div class="vertical-center" id="form-div" style="background:transparent;">
    <div class="title-body col-md-offset-3 col-md-6">
        <h1 id="main-title">Title</h1>
        <br>
        <form action="/search" method="post" class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8 main-form form-group">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Placeholder Text" class="form-control textbox"
                   name="keywords" required>
            <br>
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Asking Price" class="form-control bfh-number"
                       data-min="0" data-max="9999999" name="asking_price" required>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="col-md-10 category-selector-div">
                <select class="form-control category-selector" name="category">
                    <option selected>All Categories</option>
                    <option value="1">Cat 1</option>
                    <option value="2">Cat 2</option>
                    <option value="3">Cat 3</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" value="Search" class="submit-button btn btn-default col-md-2"
                   style="padding-left: 8px; padding-right: 8px;">
        </form>
        <br>
        <br>
        <div id="results-div" class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8">
            {% block results %}
            {% endblock %}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}

{% block footer %}
<div></div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: just a wild guess....have you cleared your cache? or tried another browser?